# Protractor baseurl reloading the page multiple times before starting the test specs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, jasmine2.0

Everytime I run the protractor command,the baseurl is reloading multiple times before starting actual test specs.Sometimes its reloading 2 times sometimes its 4-5 times.

```
exports.config = {
  plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-console',
    logLevels: ['severe']
  }],
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  baseUrl: 'https://test.com/',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
  },
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      directConnect: true,
      specs: [
        '../specs/master_spec/master.js'
      ],
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--incognito', 'disable-extensions', 'start-maximized', 'show-fps-counter=true']
      },
      name: "chrome-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 4,
    }
  ],
  maxSessions: 1  
};
```

**Gmail signup process spec file :**
In first it block,i am trying to call that baseurl from signupPage() function.I am using some more functionas from LoginModal.page file too.

```
var users = require('../../config/users.js');
var conf = require('../../config/conf.js');
var LoginModal = require('../../pages/LoginModal.page.js');
var SignupModal = require('../../pages/SignupModal.page.js');
var ConnectDatabase = require('../../dbconnections/ConnectDatabase.js');
var dbscript = require('../../dbconnections/dbscript.js');

describe('QI : ', function() {
  var page = new SignupModal();
  page = new SignupModal();
  var LoginPage = new LoginModal();
  LoginPage = new LoginModal();

  beforeEach (function(){
    var dbqueries = new dbscript();
  })

  function signupPage() {
    page.clickSignupOption();
  };

  function userIcon() {
    browser.sleep(3000);
    LoginPage.clickUsrIcon2();
  };

  function logout() {
    LoginPage.clickLogoutOp();
  };

  describe('User : ', function() {
    it('Signup with Gmail', function() {
      signupPage();
      browser.sleep(5000);
      page.clickGoogleOption();
      var winHandles = browser.getAllWindowHandles();
      winHandles.then(function(handles) {
        var parentWindow = handles[0];
        var popUpWindow = handles[1];
        browser.switchTo().window(popUpWindow);
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.sleep(6000);
        //login to gmail on the pop up window
        LoginPage.typeGmail(users.config.quantraLearner.userName);
        LoginPage.clickNextBtn();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        LoginPage.enterPswd(users.config.quantraLearner.password);
        LoginPage.clickpswdNextBtn();
        browser.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
        browser.sleep(10000);
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(conf.config.baseUrl + 'dashboard');
        userIcon();
        logout();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(conf.config.baseUrl);
        browser.sleep(5000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your spec files too.

Comment: @HaC updated the spec file :)

Comment: What's in `signupPage` and what is `page` declared as? Please post code for both. I'm guessing there might be something in there that's calling the url multiple times.

Comment: @HaC updated complete spec file,in signupPage function I am calling its selector & page is declared as signupModal which contains all required selectors.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those. Doesn't look like a code issue there, so it brings the problem back to the config.  Have you looked at this [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3171)? Sorry it seems like I'm giving you the run around, it's hard to debug someone else's code snippets.